# Count errors using Otree

Tags: python, counter, otree

I am trying to create a simple counter in Otree that give a message when I don't have the correct answer in an 0tree form and also count the total attempts that a subject did before he/she got the right answer (I am trying to count the mistakes for each subject in each question).

I have the next code, but this code don't add anything in the form when someone make a mistake.

```
class CRT1(Page):
   #def is_displayed(self):
   #return self.player.tipo == 1

form_model = 'player'
form_fields = ['CRT1', 'incorrect_attempts1']

def CRT1_error_message(self, values):
    print('Escogiste', values)
    if values != 2:
        return 'No lo olvides, sólo la respuesta seleccionada por el mayor número de los participantes en una sesión es la más seleccionada.'
        self.player.incorrect_attempts1 += 1
        print(incorrect_attempts1
```

if someone can give a idea of how to make this code works would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return before adding to the counter. Do like that:

```
def CRT1_error_message(self, values):
    print('Escogiste', values)
    if values != 2:

        self.player.incorrect_attempts1 += 1
        return 'No lo olvides, sólo la respuesta seleccionada por el mayor número de los participantes en una sesión es la más seleccionada.'
```

Be sure that `incorrect_attempts1` has `initial=0`